# Proposed deriving mechanism for Haskell

Tags: haskell, syntax, types, macros, syntactic-sugar

I am sorry if this question seems ill thought-out, but I was wondering if it would be possible to define a consistent semantics for something  like the following in Haskell:

```
derive Num String from Int where
    get = read
    set = show

derive Ord Bool from Integer where
    get = fromEnum
    set = toEnum

derive (Monad, Functor) Maybe from [] where
    get (Just x) = [x]
    get Nothing  = [ ]
    set [x]      = Just x
    set [ ]      = Nothing
```

I see no reason why not, and it seems like it would cut down on boilerplate in some situations but I don't know if (and if so, how easily) this could be implemented.

Edit:

My intention would be for e.g. the first example to be replaced with something like this:

```
instance Num String where
    get = read :: String -> Int
    set = show :: Int    -> String
    a + b = set $ get a + get b
    a * b = set $ get a * get b
    ...
```

Comment: `get`? `set`? I think you're asking about something quite unrelated to what Haskell calls deriving. You mean automatic type conversion, right? That's not a good idea; it deprives you from the benefits of bidirectional type deduction, which all in all avoids far more boilerplate than a few explicit conversion functions can reasonably introduce. — Also, these are _particularly_ bad examples, since the types aren't even approximately isomorphic. What are you going to do with problems like `get "bla" :: Int`, `set (-1) :: Bool`, or `set [1,2,3] :: Maybe Int`?

Comment: I think that it should be possible to replace the declaration with a simple instance declaration at compile time, so the type system should remain unchanged although I agree that this proposal is quite unrelated to Haskell's deriving mechanism; perhaps a name change is in order.

Comment: What declaration is supposed to be replaced by what? Can you give an example of how you'd like to use this?

Comment: The get function for the first example is admittedly partial, and my intention would be to throw a pattern match failure, but get and set would never be exposed to the user so your other two examples are irrelevant.

Comment: I still don't quite see what need you have for all this. — Your proposed `instance Num String` shows quite well one more problem: if such stuff is going on without the user seeing it, then they'll have no control about the intermediate types. Why would it be `Int`? The user might need `"3.14159" + "2.71828"`. Why would it be `Double`? The user might need `"10"^"800" - 1`. Why `Integer`, they might need `"4 :+ 1" / "15"`. etc. etc..

Comment: As a side note: your Num instance would still not allow `"42" + 27`. This would with certainty give us functional pearls like `"42" + show 27`.

Answer (score 4):

What you've described here is essentially defining class instances by isomorphism. This can obviously be achieved by defining the `get` and `set` functions, though let's call them `to` and `fro` for a little more clarity.

```
toSI   :: String -> Integer
fromSI :: Integer -> String

instance Num String where
  a + b = fromSI $ (toSI a) + (toSI b)
  abs   = fromSI . abs . toSI
  ...
```

These are indeed pretty easy definitions to write and there could be some value for reducing boilerplate by lifting class instantiation over `(to, fro)` automatically, **but** this system must carefully follow many rules in order to not pollute the global typeclass instance space with junk.

In particular, we might ask `(to, fro)` to form an isomorphism. This means that roundtrips *in both directions* are identities. Stated differently it means that given any integer `n`, I should not be able to distinguish `(froSI (toSI n))` from `n` by any means (well, some things like computational speed are ignored). Furthermore, I must have the same property for *any* string `s`: `toSI (froSI s)` must be indistinguishable from `n`.

That second one clearly fails as `"I am not a number!"` throws an error on that roundtrip. There are many reasons why throwing errors in pure code is dangerous and with typeclasses that danger would carry on and pollute the code of anyone who ever imports your code.

You might point out that this only comes about because not all strings are valid numbers. It seems like `fromSI . toSI` is always trouble, but `toSI . fromSI` ought to work. Maybe it only affects things like instantiating `instance Num String` and if we instead used our `(toSI, froSI)` pair to derive some `instance` for `Integer` that `String` has would we be in a good position. *Maybe.*

Let's try it. `String` is an instance of `Monoid` which looks like this

```
instance Monoid [a] where       -- if a ~ Char then this is String
  mempty = []
  mappend as bs = as ++ bs
```

If we implemented `mappend` via `mappend = toSI . mappend . fromSI` it gives us "concatenating integers" like

```
(1 <> 2) <> 3   ==   123
1 <> (2 <> 3)   ==   123
(0 <> 1) <> 1   ==   11
0 <> (1 <> 1)   ==   11
```

and if we're careful to define `"" -> 0` instead of making it fail then we can get a useful `mempty` too.

```
mempty = toSI mempty
```

which seems like it ought to work well. It's truly a `Monoid` of `Integer` inherited from its "one-way isomorphism" with `String` (think about why I have to use `Integer` here, not `Int`). More specifically, we can't distinguish `toSI (fromSI n)` from `n` by any test built from functions in the `Monoid` typeclass, so it's "good enough" to make this mapping.

But then we run smack into another problem. `Integer` already has a `Monoid` instance. It already has about 10 of them, the most popular being multiplication and addition

```
instance Monoid Integer            instance Monoid Integer
  mempty  = 0                        mempty  = 1
  mappend = (+)                      mappend = (*)
```

So, we're losing a lot of information by picking any one of these instances to be the *canonical* typeclass instance for Monoid. It's more accurate to state that `Integer` becomes a `Monoid` via its "one-way isomorphism" (a.k.a. "retract") with `String` but also via its stripping to just have addition but also via its stripping to just have multiplication.

Really we want to keep that information around which is why the `Monoid` package defines things like `Sum` and `Product` which indicate that this `Integer` has been specialized to just use its `Addition` properties.

And that's, at the end of the day, exactly the problem you have with lifting typeclass instances over isomorphisms at large. Usually, types have a lot of isomorphisms and retracts that can be abused in this way and it's hard to have truly canonical, law-abiding instances. When you find one, it's usually worth the code tax to write it out explicitly, even if you end up using an isomorphism to do so.

When there isn't a canonical choice you have instruments like `newtype` and a slew of libraries for quickly accessing what's just "underneath" your `newtype` layer all the way from the common `GeneralizedNewtypeDeriving` extension out to the [`Control.Newtype` package](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/newtype) or the directly inspired [`Iso`, `au` and `auf`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/lens/3.9.0.2/doc/html/Control-Lens-Iso.html#t%3aau) and entire [`Wrapped`, `ala`, `alaf`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/lens/3.9.0.2/doc/html/Control-Lens-Wrapped.html#t%3aala) mechanisms of [`lens`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens).

Essentially this machinery is all in place to make it easier to talk richly about the instances inherited over various isomorphisms, especially those induced by `newtype`.